# JavaScript/regex: Remove text between parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

Would it be possible to change

```
Hello, this is Mike (example)
```

to

```
Hello, this is Mike
```

using JavaScript with Regex?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

```
"Hello, this is Mike (example)".replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
```

Result:

```
"Hello, this is Mike"
```

Comment: note that .replace() does not change the string itself, it only returns a new string. So you still have to set the variable to be equal to what you changed.

Comment: Where the parentheses are in the middle of a string, the regex above will remove all the whitespace around them. This is probably not good.

Comment: How to do inverse of this? I want ```(example)``` only

Comment: Doesn't work if you have something like: It's a bit messed (up (right)) but it happens :)

Comment: Not a robust solution, it works on console but not within script tag for some reason tried it already many times. The other answer work just fine.

Answer (score 37):

```
var str = "Hello, this is Mike (example)";

alert(str.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/g, ''));
```

That'll also replace excess whitespace before and after the parentheses.

Comment: what's the point of question mark?

Comment: .*? is a non-greedy version of .* (match everything). In short, it matches upto the next thing it can match, in this case the closing parentheses. Google "non-greedy regex" for more details.

Answer (score 20):

Try `/ \([\s\S]*?\)/g`

***Where***

(space) matches the character   (space) literally

`\(` matches the character `(` literally

`[\s\S]` matches any character (`\s` matches any whitespace character and `\S` matches any non-whitespace character)

`*?` matches between zero and unlimited times

`\)` matches the character `)` literally

`g` matches globally

**Code Example:**

```js
var str = "Hello, this is Mike (example)";
str = str.replace(/ \([\s\S]*?\)/g, '');
console.log(str);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0}
```

Comment: what's the point of "[\s\S]" when you can just use a dot, meaning any character?

Answer (score 7):

If you need to remove text inside nested parentheses, too, then:

```
        var prevStr;
        do {
            prevStr = str;
            str = str.replace(/\([^\)\(]*\)/, "");
        } while (prevStr != str);
```

Comment: Didn't need that to get rid of the brackets but didn't want to get rid of whitespace before paranetheses like most solutions are and this maintains it so thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found this version most suitable for all cases. It doesn't remove all whitespaces.

For example "a (test)   b" -> "a b"

`"Hello, this is Mike (example)".replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, " ").trim();
 "Hello, this is (example) Mike ".replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, " ").trim();`

Comment: Beware `trim` is not universally supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim, at least it was not in 2015 ... in 2017 it looks a lot better.

Comment: fails with "this (example (here) which) is no good".  ie. nested parens!