# Replace all braced strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to make this:

```
i went to the [open shops], but the [open shops] were closed
```

look like this:

```
i went to the markets, but the markets were closed
```

with javascript replace

im not very good with regex and the square brackets need delimited im sure

Comment: Maybe a regex tutorial or an online regex tester would be a better first step?

Comment: @DaveNewton: Or even google for that matter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292468/javascript-regex-remove-text-between-brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
"i went to the [open shops], but the [open shops] were closed".replace(/\[open shops\]/g, 'markets');
```

The tricky part is the the need to escape the brackets and add the global match to replace each matching instance. For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: thanks - i was close - i was putting quotes around the whole regex thus .replace("/\[open shops\]/g","sd"). i thought the space might need escaping too. but obviously not. thanks again.

Comment: @case1352 In a regex question it might make sense to include the regex you're using.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put \ before [ and ] to treat it as a regular character. This way your regex would become `\[openshops\]`.

If you have multiple things that need to be replaced (eg. `[shops]` and `[state]`) you can do the following which dynamically creates the regex. This way you don't have to hard code it for each thing.

```
var str = "I went to the [shops], but the [shops] were [state]. I hate it when the [shops] are [state].";
    var things = {
        shops: "markets",
        state: "closed"
    };
    for (thing in things) {
        var re = new RegExp("\\["+thing+"\\]", "g");
        str = str.replace(re, things[thing]);
    }
console.log(str);
```

*Note that you need to use two backslashes instead of just one when doing it this way.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex. You could use something like.

```
    var a = "i went to the [open shops], but the [open shops] were closed";
    var replacement = "KAPOW!";

    while(a.contains("[") && a.contains("]"))
    {
        var left = a.indexOf("[");
        var right = a.indexOf("]");

        a = a.substring(0,left) + replacement + a.substring(right+ 1);
    }

    console.log(a);
```

Comment: Regex seems like a better tool in this case, though.

Comment: It's a lot easier to read a simplistic regex than several lines of code-if it isn't it's a deficiency in regex knowledge, which IMO is critical to have.

Comment: I agree regex is the better option but for beginner programmers, like just did hello world tuts level of skill, I think regex is a jump of complexity to high. But that is probably just me I was just offering an alternative that I find easier to read. I would probably just build the string differently in the first place :D.