# Javascript remove substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of the following format:

```
[text text] Text to stay
```

And I want to remove the brackets and the text inside, so that the final string will be:

```
Text to Stay
```

Is it possible to achieve this using regex and the function replace?

Comment: Probably more fitting duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292468/javascript-regex-remove-text-between-brackets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with replace function and regexp, as follow:

```
var text = "[text text] Text to stay";
var replaced = text.replace(/\[(.*)\]/, "");
```

Check this snippet:

```js
var text = "[text text] Text to stay";
var replaced = text.replace(/\[(.*)\]/, "");

document.write(replaced);
```

Comment: That would turn **`"[text text] Text to ] stay"`** into just **`" stay"`**. You should use a non-greedy matching instead.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var str = "[text text] Text to stay";
alert(str.replace(str.substr(str.indexOf('['),str.indexOf(']') - str.indexOf('[') + 1),""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this short hand.

```js
var text = "[text text] Text to stay";
var updatedText = text.split('] ')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex also works when the text includes `]`.

```js
var text = "[text text] Text to stay";
var replaced = text.replace(/\[.*?\] /, "");

document.write(replaced);
```