# Remove all parentheses, commas etc from a string and then extract the first 5 words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, eg:

```
Lenovo K6 Power (Silver, 32 GB)(4 GB RAM), smart phone
```

I want to remove all parentheses and contents within the parentheses, commas etc and then extract the first five words only so that I get the result as

```
Lenovo K6 Power smart phone
```

Is there any method to apply regex to get this result?

Comment: Don't change your question. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Changing your question is extremely rude to those who already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```js
var str = 'Lenovo K6 Power (Silver, 32 GB)(4 GB RAM)';

document.write(str.match(/\w+/g).slice(0,5).join(' '));
```

It gets all words into an array (`match(/\w+/g)`), then gets the first five (`slice(0,5)`), to join then back to a string separated by space (`join(' ')`).

(And... Considering the question is tagged with regex, I believe a word could be defined as consisting of regex *word characters*, i.e. `\w`.)

**Edit**

The question has changed so the answer isn't correct anymore. Here's an update snippet that works with the new criteria:

```js
var str = 'Lenovo K6 Power (Silver, 32 GB)(4 GB RAM), smart phone';

document.write(str.split(/(?:\W*\([^)]*\))*\W+/).slice(0,5).join(' '));
```

This one `split`'s the string instead, using the regex `(?:\W*\([^)]*\))*\W+` which will match everything but word characters (`\W`), unless they're inside parentheses (everything inside parentheses is matched).

`split`ing on that will give an array with only the desired words. Therefrom the logic is the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myString = "Lenovo K6 Power (Silver, 32 GB)(4 GB RAM), smart phone";

while (/\(.*\)/.test(myString)) {
    myString = myString.replace(/\(.*?\)/.exec(myString)[0],'');
}

console.log(myString.match(/\w+/g));
```

The first snippet matches all parentheses pairs as long as there are some and removes them, them it matches all remaining words.

Output: Obj... ["Lenovo", "K6", "Power", "smart", "phone"]

This is a general solution, to always only get the first 5 Elements change the console log to

```
var obj = myString.match(/\w+/g); 
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i ++) 
{ 
console.log(obj[i]); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are creating a regexp with the regexp constructor from a regexp literal. I don't understand how this solution will give just back the first five words in case there are more.

Comment: I tried to anser in a general way. You are right, one does not need the RegExp but i find it to be more readable. Nonetheless they are useless in this case so I removed them. To get the first five One could create an object instead of doing a console.log and iterate over it using a for/foreach. I edited my answer to show.

Answer (score 2):

```
var s1 = "Lenovo K6 Power (Silver, 32 GB)(4 GB RAM), smart phone";
var s2 = s1.replace(/\([^)]*\)|, /g,'')
console.log(s2) //Output : "Lenovo K6 Power smart phone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely trivial and can be answered with the most basic JavaScript skills. I strongly suggest you go back and review your tutorials and intros, and try solving your problem yourself.

To remove something, you simply do

```
string.replace(WHAT, '')
```

In other words, you replace something with nothing (the empty string `''`). In the case you mentioned, this, a simple Google search for something like "javascript remove regexp" will give you plenty of pointers. In this case, [one of the first results actually is about removing parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292468/javascript-regex-remove-text-between-parentheses).

In your case, I guess you finally decided you want to remove parentheses and what's inside them. In about the first five minutes of learning regexp, you should have learned to write

```
/\(.*?\)/g
 ^^              an actual left paren
   ^^^           any number of characters
      ^^         an actual right paren
         ^       match this over and over again
```

If you need help with this, try an online regexp tester such as regex101.com. It will also give you a readable version of your regexp.

The only thing moderately advanced about this is the `.*?`, where the `?` means "non-greedy"--in other words, take characters up only to the **next** right paren.

I'm sure you already learned why you have to write `\(` to match a left parenthesis, right? The `\` escapes the parentheses, because by itself the parentheses would have a special meaning to regexp. You know the `g` flag too, right? That means replace **all** the matches.

To find the first five tokens, you first need to split your string into tokens. I'm sure you recall from your studies the basic `Array` methods, including--drum roll--**`split`**! Split your string with `string.split(' ')`. That will split on single spaces. If you want to split on any whitespace, you could try `string.split(/\s+/)`.

Now go back and read the documentation for `split` real carefully, although I know you already have. Look carefully at the second argument, called `limit`. It does exactly what you want. It splits into segments, but no more than specified by limit.

The solution to your problem, which you could easily have come up with if you had spent about five minutes studying the documentation and experimenting, is

```
input.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, '').split(/\s+/, 5)
```

Unfortunately, your approach of posting on Stack Overflow is not going to scale well at all. You can't post here every time there is some minor problem you cannot figure out yourself. To be perfectly frank, if you cannot **learn how to learn**, then you better give up on being a programmer and try brick-laying instead. You need to learn how to figure out things yourself. Before anything else, you need to learn how to read (and digest) the documentation. Very early in your career, you're also going to need to learn how to debug your programs, since Stack Overflow is no better a way to get your programs debugged than it is to get them written for you in the first place. If you simply cannot bring yourself to read documents or learn by yourself, and can only work by asking other people how to do every little thing, then find a chat room or forum where there are people with nothing better to do than answer such questions. That is not what Stack Overflow is.

```js
console.log('Lenovo K6 Power (Silver, 32 GB)(4 GB RAM), smart phone'.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, '').split(/\s+/, 5));
```

Fixing this code so as to remove the comma is left as an exercise for you to use your new-found learning powers on. Hint: you may want to use the regexp feature called "alternation", which is represented by the vertical bar or pipe `|`. You may also find yourself needing to use **character classes**, which is another thing you should have learned about very early in your regexp studies.

None of this has anything to do with TypeScript, or Angular, as you seem to have thought when you initially posted the question. It's a little concerning that you seem to think that doing basic regexp or string or array manipulation would somehow be a TypeScript or Angular issue. TypeScript is merely a typing layer on top of JavaScript. Angular is a framework for building web apps. Neither replaces JavaScript, or provides any new basic language capability. In fact, to use either effectively, you **must** know JavaScript well.