# How to remove string between specified characters and store the removed string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a string:

```
"but i [C#min] do [G#min] believe there's"
```

How to I turn that string into:

```
"but i  do  believe there's" (basically removing everything in-between '[' and ']')
```

And I would like to have `[C#min]` & `[G#min]` stored in an another array.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Not following the logic

Comment: use regex to get what is inside the brackets

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, you might be able to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/4292483/212869 this will return a new string without the text between the brackets (after being edited suitably). Storing the removed items removes their context. You'd need to store position data too.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var a = "but i [C#min] do [G#min] believe there's";
    console.log(a.replace(/\[(.[^\[\]]*)\]/g, '')); // "but i  do  believe there's"
    console.log(a.match(/\[(.[^\[\]]*)\]/g)); // ["[C#min]", "[G#min]"]
```

The RegExp matches for everything between `[`, `]` except for `[`, `]` themselves.

You might need to remove extra white spaces left around the replacements.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regular expression:

```js
    var text = "but i [C#min] do [G#min] believe there's";
    var regexp = /(\[[^\]]*\])/g;

    var matches = text.match(regexp);
    text = text.replace(regexp, '').replace(/  /g, ' ');
    console.log(text);
```

`matches` will contain the array `["[C#min]", "[G#min]"]`.

*Note:* the second `replace` for text handles the incorrectly remaining double spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this straightforward way:

```js
    var str = "but i [C#min] do [G#min] believe there's";
    
    var start, stop, newStr = '', removed = '', counter =1;
    while(str.search(/\[.*\]/g) > 0) {
      start = str.indexOf('[');
      stop = str.indexOf(']');
      newStr += str.substring(0, start);
      removed += str.substring(start, stop+1);
      str =  str.substring(stop+1, str.length);
      counter++;
      if(counter > 3) break;
    }
    newStr += str;
    
    console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Regex, simple way:

```js
    var string = "but i [C#min] do [G#min] believe there's";
    array = []; 
    filteredString = ""
    
    for (i=0;i<string.length;i++){
        
        if (string[i] != '[') {
            filteredString += string[i];
            continue;
        }
        newstring = ""+string[i];
        do {
                newstring += string[++i]; 
            
        } while (string[i]!=']');
        array.push(newstring);
    }

console.log(array);
console.log(filteredString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to find the bracketed strings and then strip them out with `String.replace()`. The stripped out portions will be in an array for whatever use you need them for.

```js
var input = "but i [C#min] do [G#min] believe there's";
var reg = /\[(.*?)\]/g;           // Patthen to find
var matches = input.match(reg);   // Find matches and populate array with them
var output = input.replace(reg, "").replace(/\s\s/g, " ");  // Strip out the matches and fix spacing
console.log(matches); // Just for testing
console.log(output);  // Result
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by [:

```
function parseString(input) {
    output = {
        values: [],
        result: ""
    };
    input = input.split('[');
    for (var index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
        var closingPosition = input[index].indexOf("]");
        if ((index > 0) && (closingPosition + 1)) {
            output.values.push('[' + input[index].substring(0, closingPosition) + ']');
            if (input[index].length > closingPosition) {
                output.result += input[index].substring(closingPosition + 1);
            }
        } else {
            output.result += input[index];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```