# Removing the links from reddit comments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading the comments from under reddit posts.

Some of the comments have links, that I would like to get rid of.

Example (input):

```
This is a [pic](https://i.imgur.com/yKmUMJD.jpg), [this](http://www.google.com) is a link
```

How I would like the string to look (output):

> This is a pic, this is a link

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292468/javascript-regex-remove-text-between-parentheses), and the following line does the trick:

```
item.data.body.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "").replace('[', '').replace(']', '');
```

I would like to know how can I add `http` to the regex, so it will not remove the "normal" bracket text as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw you had posted a similar question earlier. Now you have also posted what you have tried... looks like you are struggling with this one.

Here's what I would do:

```js
const str = "This is a [pic](https://i.imgur.com/yKmUMJD.jpg), [this](http://www.google.com) is a link";

const tags = str.match(/\[.*?(?=\]\((.*?)\))/g).map(x => x.substring(1));
const newString = str.replace(/\[.*?\]\(.*?\)/g, () => {
  return tags.shift();
});

console.log(newString)
```

First step is to find all of the marked up text. In other words, everything wrapped in `[]`. In your example above, this will yield the array `[pic, this]`.

Then, we need to replace the whole url bbcode (i.e the `[xxx](http://url)`) with each of our matches above. We treat our array as a queue, and remove each result from the array with `shift()` once we've  used it.

Of course, this solution isn't fool-proof. It won't handle the corner-case in which any of the characters `()[]` are *part of* either the markup or the URL itself.