# Removing links from a reddit comments using python and regex

Tags: python, regex, reddit

I want to remove links in the format Reddit uses

```
comment = "Hello this is my [website](https://www.google.com)"

no_links = RemoveLinks(comment)

# no_links == "Hello this is my website"
```

I found a [similar question about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411923/removing-the-links-from-reddit-comments), but I don't know how to translate it to python.

I am not that familiar with regex so I would appreciate it if you explained what's happening.

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow. You do not show any code or regex, please provide your tries as [mre] and explain what went wrong: see [ask]

Comment: Isn't the javascript and regex code from the link I included enough..?

Comment: No, it is not. Every question should contain all relevant information itself. SO is no language translation service - you are supposed to try yourself.

Comment: In fact I did try a lot. I'm not that good with searching the web, which I do for hours. I did not see the point in giving more information about a problem like this. But I'll be sure to include all my failed attempts so I can appear like I have put in more effort. I assumed it wouldn't take that long for someone who knows about this to help... I'm asking a question, isn't that the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)')
comment = "Hello this is my [website](https://www.google.com)"

print(pattern.sub(r'\1', comment))
```

The line:

```
pattern = re.compile('\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)')
```

creates a regex pattern that will search for anything surrounded by square brackets, followed by anything surrounded by parenthesis, the `'?'` indicates that they should match as little text as possible (non-greedy).

The function `sub(r'\1', comment)` replaces a match by the first capturing group in this case the text inside the brackets.

For more information about regex I suggest you read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).